# Formula conversion Octave to NumPy

Tags: numpy, octave, radians

I am calculating the following lines in Octave:

```
DOA = [2.44511697; 171.03810943; -54.15891743; -106.57844237];
alfa = tand(DOA);

   0.042701
  -0.157703
  -1.384441
   3.359049
```

in radians I get the following results in Octave:

```
alfa = tan(DOA);

  -0.8363
   5.5366
  -0.9350
   0.2402
```

The second gives me the same results in NumPy:

```
alfa = np.tan(DOA)
[[-0.83628155]
 [ 5.53658766]
 [-0.93504359]
 [ 0.24017226]]
```

when converting to degrees with np.rad2deg I get the following results instead:

```
alfa = np.tan(DOA)
alfa = np.rad2deg(alfa)

[[-47.91540317]
 [317.22310577]
 [-53.57405123]
 [ 13.76085667]]
```

I couldn't find a suitable answer to this issue. I would appreciate it, if someone could help me with this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is quite some confusion here. The result of a tangent is not an angle, and therefore converting the result of `tan` into radians is meaningless. Its like converting temperature to radians or speed to radians. Can't do it, its meaningless. you may however want to convert DOA to radians?

Comment: `tand` accepts a degrees argument.  To get the same with `np.tan` you need to first convert the degrees to radians.  Same as with using the Octave `tan`

Comment: Upon cross-checking with my Ocyave outputs, I found that the following calculation brought me the right solution: alfa = np.tan(DOA*np.pi/180). Hope it helps for others too